# How to analyiz the HTTP Post request

Tags: http, post, http-headers, sms, sms-gateway

If there is a SMS service that makes a `HTTP` request, Can we know the HTTP request that sent the message and retrieve it's information ?? `url` and `post` headers ?

Comment: Why don't use [WireShark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) ?

Comment: OK, I hope I am asking the right question. what i want is to know what happens when I send sms though a website  after entering the user name and password) of course

Comment: yeah, what browser are you using? In Chrome, just hit F12 then go to the Network tab to view HTTP requests.

Comment: @Arvin I have already did this, but no http requests when sending the message!! is it possible to send SMS without a HTTP requests ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which API is being used, then yes, you can work out everything except the username and password.  If you don't know the API or site being used then you have no chance.

As for alternatives to HTTP APIs, yes there are some (e.g. email gateways), but they all still end up with SMPP servers eventually.